# How to do a MapReduce in java with MongoSpark and JavaRdd

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to do a mapReduce in java, using MongoSpark and rdd (JavaMongoRdd). So currently, I am able to retrieve my mongo document in my Rdd but I don't know how to proceed after that. In fact I have a field in my document which is a date and I want to use the year in this date to do my mapReduce but I don't find anything on how to do this. So I am here to asking you if you have some documentation, tutorial or even an example of how to proceed.

Here the code, I am trying to have a pairRdd with the Mongo document and the year, to count the number of document for each year but i don't know if it is the way I have to proceed

```
 public String count() {
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
    JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
    logger.info("test 1 :" + rdd.count());
    logger.info("test 2 :" + rdd.first().toJson());

    /*JavaMongoRDD<Document> newRdd = rdd.withPipeline(
            Collections.singletonList(
                    Document.parse("{ $match: { _id : { $gt : ObjectId(\"5c9e180cdba48525f0df30b9\") } } }")
            )
    );*/

    //logger.info("test 2.5 :" +newRdd.first());

    JavaPairRDD<String, Document> pairRdd = rdd
            .mapToPair((document) -> new Tuple2(document.getString("date").split(".")[1], document));
    logger.info("test 3 :" + pairRdd.first());
    //logger.info("test 2 :" + rdd.first().toJson());
    //ar
    //logger.info("test spark");
    return "test";
}
```

My MongoDb documents looks like this

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c9e180ddba48525f0df30cb"),
    "title" : "Redevance: une perte de compétitivité pour l’hydraulique suisse",
    "description" : [
            "Le Parlement a bouclé, durant cette session de printemps, la révision de la loi sur les forces hydrauliques. La solution adoptée aboutit au statu quo sur le plan de la redevance hydraulique. Le taux maximal de cette taxe reste ainsi fixé à 110 francs par kilowatt théorique, jusqu'à fin 2024. Les..."
    ],
    "date" : "dimanche, 24. mars 2019"
```

Comment: provide some code.

Comment: I added the little bit of code that I have done

Comment: is the issue with getting the date or using the maping and reducing fuctions?

Comment: the issue is using the map and reducing functions, when I speak of the date is just to explain what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do something like this.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> pairRdd = rdd.mapToPair((document) ->{
   String date = document.getString("date");
   String year = date.split(" ")[date.split(" ").length-1];// get the year
   return new Tuple2(year,1L);  //create pair of year and 1L the count for this row. 
}
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> counts = pairRdd.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);// for all matching keys in the list accumulate the value
```

counts should be a map like 1999->30, 2000->24...

also  you can get year like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEEE, dd. MMMM yyyy", Locale.FRANCE);
LocalDate d = df.parse(date).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(d.getYear());
```